# Accessing original local time from Joda DateTime object

Tags: json, timezone, jackson, deserialization, jodatime

I have the following JSON string that is being converted into a Joda DateTime object (Using Jackson)

```
"2015-08-02T11:30:00.000+01:00"
```

Printing out the time using the below code

```
DateTimeFormatter timeFmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");
String timePart = timeFmt.print(dt);
```

I get:

*10:30*

Which is the correct UTC time.

However I want to be able to print out the original local time

*11:30*

How can I get this (or even the original offset of +01:00) from my date time object?

Thanks,

Kenny

Comment: How do you convert into DateTime? Can you add your serializer to your question?

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you sooner, I was on vacation.
I am using Spring restTemplate.exchange which under the hood uses Jackson for deserialization. 
I believe I need to add in a custom object mapper for Jackson to handle dateTime as the default loses the local time information and just converts to UTC. I haven't done this yet, but will try this now and update when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found a solution. It is not the most elegant, I would rather have registered the custom object mapper in the application context.xml but could not get that working..

Anyway the reason that I am getting UTC back during deserialization as that is what the DateTime deserializer supplied by Jackson purposely does:

```
public ReadableInstant deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        JsonToken t = jp.getCurrentToken();
        if(t == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT)
            return new DateTime(jp.getLongValue(), DateTimeZone.UTC);
        if(t == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING)
        {
            String str = jp.getText().trim();
            if(str.length() == 0)
                return null;
            else
                return new DateTime(str, DateTimeZone.UTC);
        } else
        {
            throw ctxt.mappingException(getValueClass());
        }
    }
```

So I created a custom Object Mapper

```
public class CustomObjectMapper extends ObjectMapper {

public CustomObjectMapper() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("DateTime", Version.unknownVersion());
    module.addDeserializer(DateTime.class, new dateDeserializer());
    super.registerModule(module);
}

public class dateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DateTime> {

    @Override
    public DateTime deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

  JsonToken t = jp.getCurrentToken();
  String str = jp.getText().trim();
  if (str.length() == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  else {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withOffsetParsed();
    return formatter.parseDateTime(str);
  }
    }

}
```

}

And then registered this with the rest template

```
private MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter() {
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    converter.setObjectMapper(new CustomObjectMapper());
    return converter;
}

restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(0, mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter());
```

If anybody has any improvements or thoughts on this would love to hear them.

Thanks,

Kenny